# How to organize common columns to a single table?

Tags: postgresql, schema

I'm very new to database designing and I'm creating a small project to understand it better, I'm trying to come up with a new school crm. I started with the below schema:

```
create table student(
    id int not null, 
    firstname varchar(100),
    lastname varchar(100),
    PRIMARY key (id)
);

create table address(
    id int not null, 
    street varchar(30) not null,
    city varchar(30) not null, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

-- they have own roles for app
create table guardians(
    id int not null, 
    firstname varchar(100),
    lastname varchar(100),
    primary key (id)
);

--  teacher have own roles
create table teacher(
    id int not null, 
    firstname varchar(100),
    lastname varchar(100),
    PRIMARY key (id)
)
```

`guardians` and `teachers` will have `password` for login the web portal. The reason why I created separate table is mainly because `teachers` might have column's like `salary`, `schoolId` etc in the future. But now if I look at the schema here, mostly the `firstName`, `lastname` is common for all `student`, `teacher` and `guardians`.

How can I have a common table for such repeatable field names? Or this design is good? Also I wanted to have another table `ROLE` which going to give **permissions** at app level to update/insert certain tables. Not sure how can I design it as well.

Comment: One thing you could consider is creating a ```person```  (or some-such) table and then have the ```teacher```, ```parent```, and even ```student``` tables have a foreign key relationship to that table. This would also allow you to accommodate the situation where a teacher is also a legal guardian of a student.

Comment: PostgreSQL allows [inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/tutorial-inheritance.html) which might work? I'm not sure that I get all of the hoo-hah over having a "common-things" table. If you have teachers as a distinct entity, then model it as such. Obviously, parents won't have salaries. However, teachers might be parents - but I think I'd have such as two distinct rows - one in the parent table and one in the teacher table. Try out a few things and see - schema design is an [iterative process](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A34007+iterative+process) - check links within